# How to extract full url with HtmlAgilityPack - C#

Tags: c#, hyperlink, html-agility-pack, extract

Alright with the way below it is extracting only referring url like this

the extraction code :

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in hdDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    lsLinks.Add(link.Attributes["href"].Value.ToString());
}
```

The url code

```
<a href="Login.aspx">Login</a>
```

The extracted url

```
Login.aspx
```

But i want to get real link what browser parsed like

```
http://www.monstermmorpg.com/Login.aspx
```

I can do it with checking the url whether containing http and if not add the domain value but it may cause some problems at some occasions and i think not a very wise solution.

c# 4.0 , HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.0

Comment: You need to consider the URL, if there is a `base` element in the parsed document and whether the paths are relative, absolute or external.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you have the original url, you can combine the parsed url something like this:

```
// The address of the page you crawled
var baseUrl = new Uri("http://example.com/path/to-page/here.aspx");

// root relative
var url = new Uri(baseUrl, "/Login.aspx");
Console.WriteLine (url.AbsoluteUri); // prints 'http://example.com/Logon.aspx'

// relative
url = new Uri(baseUrl, "../foo.aspx?q=1");
Console.WriteLine (url.AbsoluteUri); // prints 'http://example.com/path/foo.aspx?q=1'

// absolute
url = new Uri(baseUrl, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760286/");
Console.WriteLine (url.AbsoluteUri); // prints 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760286/'

// other...
url = new Uri(baseUrl, "javascript:void(0)");
Console.WriteLine (url.AbsoluteUri); // prints 'javascript:void(0)'
```

Note the use of `AbsoluteUri` and not relying on `ToString()` because `ToString` decodes the URL (to make it more "human-readable"), which is **not** typically what you want.

Comment: but what if lets say the crawled url is : http://www.vatanbilgisayar.com/Ev%20Bak%C4%B1m%20%C3%9Cr%C3%BCn%C3%BC/kenwood-vc-6850-vc-6850-torbasiz-elektrikli-supurge/productdetails.aspx?I_ID=40410  so how would i get real url in this question ?

Comment: What about relative/rooted paths? What if there is a `base` element?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG It'll still work - I've updated the answer with another example

Comment: @Oded good point on `<base href='...'>` tags, you need to take these into account also

Comment: hello. thanks for updated. so this baseurl is crawled url right ? also some links are containing non english characters how can i solve that problem. i think it is encoding problem.

Comment: document encoding is utf8 but still getting links like this http://www.vatanbilgisayar.com/Ev Bak�m �r�n�/products.aspx?L2=DAPEVB  and 1 more problem. it is also getting javascripts like this one : javascript: void(0)  how to fix both problems thank you.

Comment: Yes baseUrl is the crawled URL. Non-english characters should be fine.

Comment: Another thing which might help: you should really use `Uri`'s `AbsoluteUri` to get the Url so it doesn't get decoded - I'll update the answer.

Comment: yes absolute uri solved that encoding problem. only problem remaining is it is getting javascripts as link. i can check whether containing http or not but are there any more efficient solution ?

Comment: Try `if (url.Scheme == "javascript") ...`

Answer (score 2):

> I can do it with checking the url whether containing http and if not add the domain value

That's what you should do. Html Agility Pack has nothing to help you with this:

```
var url = new Uri(
    new Uri(baseUrl).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path), 
    link.Attributes["href"].Value)
);
```

Comment: thanks but lets say the crawled url is : http://www.vatanbilgisayar.com/Ev%20Bak%C4%B1m%20%C3%9Cr%C3%BCn%C3%BC/kenwood-vc-6850-vc-6850-torbasiz-elektrikli-supurge/productdetails.aspx?I_ID=40410  - in this case how can i get ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, you could use `var url = new Uri(new Uri(baseUrl).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path), link.Attributes["href"].Value));`.

Comment: your syntax is incorrect and could now solve the problem. so it does not work and gives error. also the base url means the crawled page url right